# How can I make Internet Explorer 10 light up the favorites star when I'm on a bookmarked page?

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I would like to know if the page I'm on has already been "favorited" or bookmarked before by having the star light up when I'm on a bookmarked page.  Is there functionality in IE 10 that does this?  Otherwise, I will sometimes find myself bookmarking a page more than once.

Answer (score 1):

No "built in" functionality for this that I am aware of.